# How to custom ejs delimeters in harpjs?

Tags: ejs, harp

[harp js](http://harpjs.com/faq)  seems to be a very useful tool to me.

they suppor ejs compile,but, I didn't find how to get the ejs [custom delimiters](https://github.com/tj/ejs#custom-delimiters) function support.

I want to replace <% %> with new tokens such as  {{}}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hasn’t been made configurable within Harp, sorry. We do our best to set useful defaults rather than making everything configurable, so you don’t have to worry about setting things up. It also means that boilerplates, docs, and blog posts will still be relevant for anyone using EJS.

If it’s really necessary for your particular project, and you would still like to use Harp, you could fork [Terraform (Harp’s pre-processing engine)](https://github.com/sintaxi/terraform) and modify the settings, but personally I would recommend just using the default delimiters.